# What is this font used in Apollo / early Shuttle NASA documents? (possibly OT)

Tags: nasa, history, space-art

Seeking the name of a font used in Apollo NASA documentation and some early shuttle documents as well.

Examples:

[image]

from [SSME Pocket Data Book](https://ia800704.us.archive.org/13/items/PocketDataRIRD87142SpaceShuttleMainEngine/Pocket_Data_RI-RD87-142_Space_Shuttle_Main_Engine.pdf)

[image]

From [Apollo 12 / SA 507 Flight Manual](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap12fj/pdf/a12_sa507-flightmanual.pdf)

Recognizing this question may be off-topic for this group; if so, please advise as to the appropriate stack.

Comment: This is probably OT here; font ID questions are common in the Graphic Design SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MyFonts' ["WhatTheFont" tool](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont) can match a font from an image. It suggests [Erbar Medium Condensed](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/erbar-at/medium-condensed/). I would have thought it was a [Futura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futura_(typeface)), but the S and M look more like [Erbar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erbar_(typeface)).

Comment: Wonderful! I've wondered this for years, but just thought to ask. And thanks for the link to the tool.

Comment: after seeing [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41418/how-were-video-tape-recorders-adapted-to-work-in-orbit-in-1962#comment135036_41428) (which isn't the case) I don't want to give its author the satisfaction of seeing me accept my own answer. Is there any chance that [your answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41424/12102) can be adjusted to satisfy the question in a general way, at least as a "proof of concept"? Your last comment leaves you in the air on a parabolic arc headed towards [the gorge of eternal peril](https://youtu.be/SzS9YsJX14k), never a good thing!