# How did the TIROS video tape recorders record and playback images rather than audio; how were the signals modulated?

Tags: history, photography, video, image-processing, tiros-spacecraft

(At least) one answer to [How were video tape recorders adapted to work in orbit in 1962?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41418/12102) argues that the recorder should not be called a "video" tape recorder because the record/playback head was static and not scanning the tape, and links to <s>NASA Technical Note TN D-1542 [A Precision Endless-Loop Magnetic Tape Recorder for Space Applications](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19630003221.pdf) which covers the AC system that maintains the motor's constant speed, but not the recording and playback electronics.</s>

**update:** it now links to [Contract No. NAS5-3173; Final Engineering Report, TIROS-X Meteorological Satellite System, Volume I](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19660017475.pdf) *which may in fact contain the answer to this question.*

**However** if this were a conventional tape recorder and you just took the amplified output of the vidicon and drove an audio record head with it, **it would not work when playing back.** For example a solid white area or solid back area would result in constant magnetization of the tape and therefore zero output independent of brightness level; the signal during playback would be proportional to dB/dt in the head.

Simply put, conventional tape recorders have a low frequency cut-off; they do not record long stretches of DC levels that a video signal would contain if looking at a blank gray level, **which a video tape recorder absolutely must do!**

So they must have used some modulation or encoding scheme to convert brightness levels to a modulated carrier tone of some kind (e.g. AM, FM, something else) so that a signal would be present during playback even for constant brightness levels.

**Question:** How did they do this? How did they make an otherwise audio tape recorder function as a video signal recorder and playback device?

Comment: I know that you can’t do standard parallel track recording, like you do with audio, for the reasons you state. In the 50s, helical read/write was the solution, but I’m no expert. This looks like a lot of good data.

 https://books.google.com/books?id=Qc1YF5VM-ZQC&pg=PA570&lpg=PA570&dq=helical+scan+recording+in+spacecraft&source=bl&ots=Mi8bqOLCCe&sig=ACfU3U20nlaI3g1xlnYU1xdsntZove_7LA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3qtyQsZrqAhUal3IEHcgqDXUQ6AEwAnoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=helical%20scan%20recording%20in%20spacecraft&f=false

Comment: it was standard single track linear recording @AnthonyStevens - it was only taking one picture every 30 seconds, so writing them to 100 inches of tape over two seconds was quite doable.

Comment: Audio tape recorders have similar issues when used for audio. [AC bias has been used to compensate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_bias) since the early part of the 20th century.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your linked document the video signal from the vidicon (in record mode)

> The composite video resulting from vidicon readout is applied through
> the emitter follower to the modulator and produces frequency
> variations in the 85-kc subcarrier oscillator. This FM signal is then
> applied through the head driver to the video record head of the tape
> recorder.

The specs for the vidicon video bandwidth of 62.5 kHz allowed an FM range of 85 $\pm$ 31.25 kHz, or 53.75 to 116.25 kHz to be recorded.

This means that the video signal frequency modulated a 85 kHz 'carrier'. The tape recorder operated at 50 inches per second for 2 seconds per image (compared to 7.5 ips for consumer audio recording/playback) and this speed allowed the system to record that relatively high frequency signal for later playback

Edit- Additional trivia...

Data recorders were capable of recording fairly high frequency signals. This [Ampex brochure](http://reel2reeltexas.com/AmpexDataBrochure.pdf) lists some (large) models with bandwidths up to 2 MHz.

Comment: Wow! That's a heck of a frequency swing. Thank you for your concise yet thorough and well-sourced answer! 50 ips is 1270 mm/sec which means 116250 Hz results in a linear period of 10 microns along the tape which means the tape head *azimuth* alignment https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHhfi.jpg (from [here](http://www.muzines.co.uk/articles/tape-line-up/1647)) needed to remain intact despite those incredible vibration testing procedures outlined in [NASA Technical Note TN D-1542](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19630003221.pdf):

Comment: "...sinusoidal vibration test levels of 10 g from 0 to 2000 cps for 30 minutes total sweep time, and white noise random vibration of 20 g rms in a frequency bandwidth from 5 to 2000 cps for 4 minutes."

Comment: Yup. And everything else on TIROS had to hang together under the same abuse. Tape drives can be outrageously rugged...

Comment: This is amazing stuff, I had no idea this existed but it certainly makes sense. I see for example AR-16 series 800 Hz to 2 MHz at 120 ips and FR-1600 2 MHz direct (400 kHz FM) *at up to 240 ips!*